# Parallax-Animation with transform3d, throttle, requestAnimationFrame, will-change still laggy on Mobile and Desktop, Chrome and Safari

Tags: javascript, css, parallax

I am currently try to develop a small lightweight vanilla-js parallax-library which gives the possibility to parallax elements (images, videos, sliders, ...) horizontally and vertically in both directions without any background-position things.

It works very well so far and does a great job expecting one important detail: Sometimes it's still laggy. I've tested it on Mac OS and iPhone, in Safari and Chromebrowser. For all the same.

I have tried to use the common practices like throttling, requestAnimationFrame and CSS's will-change but without success.

I am not sure, if it's possible to see the lags here in [this video](https://jmp.sh/7W8vbN9).

But I made an example where you could test it:
https://codepen.io/flexplosion/pen/RwgQXxo?editors=1111

Someone has an idea, how I can improve the scrolling-performance for the parallax?

```
var parallaxes = document.getElementsByClassName('parallax');

const windowInnerHeight = window.innerHeight;

function throttle (callback, limit) {
    var wait = false;                 // Initially, we're not waiting
    return function () {              // We return a throttled function
        if (!wait) {                  // If we're not waiting
            callback.call();          // Execute users function
            wait = true;              // Prevent future invocations
            setTimeout(function () {  // After a period of time
                wait = false;         // And allow future invocations
            }, limit);
        }
    }
 }


Array.from(parallaxes).forEach((parallax) => {
    const movement = parseFloat(parallax.dataset.movement),
        direction = parallax.dataset.direction,
        element = parallax.children[0];
    
    if( direction == 'horizontal' ) {
        // Prepare for orzintal
        element.style.height = '100%';
        element.style.width = (100 + movement) + "%";

    } else {
        // Otherwise prepare for vertical
        element.style.height = (100 + movement) + "%";
        element.style.width = '100%';
    }
});

const handleScroll = () => {
    var parallaxes = document.getElementsByClassName('parallax');
    Array.from(parallaxes).forEach((parallax) => {
        const movement = parseFloat(parallax.dataset.movement),
            direction = parallax.dataset.direction,
            reverse = parallax.dataset.reverse === 'true',
            element = parallax.children[0];

        var containerReact = parallax.getBoundingClientRect();
        var scrolledInContainer = 0 - (containerReact.top -  windowInnerHeight);
        var scrollArea = windowInnerHeight + containerReact.height;
        var progress = scrolledInContainer / scrollArea;
        var scrolledInContainer = window.pageYOffset - (containerReact.top - windowInnerHeight);
        
        if(progress > 0 && progress < 1) {
            
            requestAnimationFrame(() => {
                var position = reverse
                    ? movement * progress
                    : movement - movement * progress;
                
                element.style[ direction == 'horizontal' ? 'left' : 'top'] = "-" + position + "%";
            });
        }
    });
}

// Initialize
handleScroll();

// Hook into event
window.addEventListener('scroll', throttle(handleScroll, 10) );
```

#### UPDATE 1:

I tried to switch the script to use translate3d instead of top/left properties. The animation on Desktop (Chrome) is now ultra-smooth. Exactly how it should be. In Safari and all mobile Browsers it didn't really help...

https://codepen.io/flexplosion/pen/BaZrKYv

In Safari (same on mobile Chrome and Safari): https://jmp.sh/n4JG8J5
In Chrome: https://jmp.sh/EMM7y1Z

Comment: Using transforms instead should be more efficient.

Comment: @Shikkediel Feels even worse: https://codepen.io/flexplosion/pen/BaZrKYv

Comment: Parallax on mobile has historically been a challenge (just search for 'parallax mobile' in your search engine of choice). It usually comes down to the `scroll` event not firing on every frame update on mobile to preserve processing power. I believe some libraries get around this by overriding the native scroll by putting everything inside a touch-responsive div that offsets its content based on an internal scrolling variable, but then it becomes a lot more complicated to implement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right, so,
Your parallax implementation is very basic and should definitely be able to run every 10ms, even on the crappiest mobile device you can find. Why it doesn't has to do with a few flaws, two of which are critical.

### 1. Your throttle function doesn't do anything

Animations can get costly when you have to recalculate stuff every single frame. Naturally, you wanted to help the processor out by limiting the animation to every so many ticks. However, inside your throttle function, you merely set a `wait` variable and don't do anything with it. The throttle function ends up hurting the implementation — for *every* scroll event (which are *a lot*, possibly more than 1 per frame, go figure), you trigger the recalculations and then create a timeout that alters the `wait` variable without any purpose.

For a throttle function to work, you will have to keep track of a state that is known to *all* of its calls. This change requires the most rethinking of everything I mention here and is shown below.

### 2. <strike>The eventlistener should be `passive`</strike>

**EDIT:**
See the first comment below this answer. I had remembered optimizing scrolling behavior by adding this option, but those optimizations were done by adding the flag to *other* eventListeners that could prevent the browser from going on with the rest of the events.

**ORIGINAL:**
eventListeners can take an `options` argument. Among other things, it can contain a `passive` flag that, if set to `true`, tells the browser that you won't trigger `event.preventDefault()` inside the callback. This helps the browser, because it doesn't have to run the entire function to figure out if it should even go on with the event. Where this optimization comes from isn't entirely clear to me, but I guess it has to do with the way events are propagated.

### 3. You re-query the parallax elements on every iteration

A simple optimization that doesn't need much of an explanation, I think. You query the parallax elements at the start of the script and don't need to re-query them every time you recalculate the parallax state. This optimization is literally a matter of removing 1 line from the code.

Here is [a Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/GustvandeWal/opbLd8ur/) with all of the changes and here is the `scrollHandler` part because I can't post without showing code:

```
const scrollHandler = (() => {
  const ret = { active: false }
  let timeout

  ret.activate = function activate() {
    if (ret.active) clearTimeout(timeout)
    else {
      ret.active = true
      requestAnimationFrame(runParallax)
    }
    timeout = setTimeout(() => ret.active = false, 100)
  }

  return ret
})()
```

The throttle functionality is part of its returned object. It contains a flag `active` and a method `activate`. If you activate it, a timeout will deactivate it after 20ms. This means that

- The animation runs as soon as there's scrolling by doing `scrollHandler.activate()`.
- Then runs once every frame by doing `if (scrollHandler.active) requestAnimationFrame(runParallax)`
- Then stops 20ms after the user stopped scrolling.

I also changed some minor things, like added template literals and did some destructuring. One change you might find interesting is that you don't *need* to cast `HTMLCollection`s to an array before being able to `forEach` them. Just call `Array`'s `forEach` directly with the collection as its context. As long as you pass it an iterable, it will work.

Here are some other, less important, things of notice:

- I added a pseudo element to indicate where the `.visual` parent is located and how the inner element moves. This was, you can clearly see that the parallax elements move precisely from edge to edge.
- You also checked `> 0` and `< 1`, but these should probably be `>= 0` and `<= 1` or even better `> -0.1` and `< 1.1`, so that they are moved in the right place before you enter the screen. This prevents a sudden flicker/movement when the element comes into view.
- The part that said `.call()` was unnecessary. If you aren't planning on giving your function a new context, you can just use `()`.

Lastly, as discussed, the `direction` and `reverse` attributes are now replaced with a single `angle` attribute that maps to two values for the X and Y directions. This way, the `translate3d` can be formatted like this: `` `translate3d(${position * multipliers[0]}px, ${position * multipliers[1]}px, 0)` ``. It might seem verbose, but simply always running a calculation with a chance of the outcome constancly being useless (`0`, that is) is often faster than doing even a single `if` statement.

Sorry for the incredibly long answer

Comment: While the part about passive event listeners might be true, it does not apply to the `scroll` event which is used in this case. It is not cancelable and thereby already passive.

Comment: @Shikkediel Thanks for pointing that out. Will change this error when I have the chance.

Comment: @rakete You are spot on in your last comment

Comment: Made some updates on your code: https://codepen.io/flexplosion/pen/rNwZMYm?editors=0010

Comment: @rakete I'm changing my answer but stumbled into an inconsistency. You increase the width or height with a certain **percentage**, but move the images in **pixels**. Which of the two do you want? E.g. if `movement` is set to `100`, should the image be of size `100% + 100px` and move a total of `100px`, or should it be of size `100% + 100%` and then move `50%`?

Comment: Good morning! To switch to translate3d, some more calculations need to be added (top: 20% != translateY(20%)). I skipped this yesterday just for testing. But, I think working with pixels makes more sense as this would mean, the movement speed would be the same on all device. Currently, with percentage, there is much more movement on mobile devices as the parallax-elements are higher most of the time.

Comment: Switched it to "px". In general it definitely feels far smoother now: https://codepen.io/flexplosion/full/rNwZMYm

One last painpoint is that this horizontal dark mountain-parallax flickers when scrolling up (see here: https://jmp.sh/jftre8B ). At the moment, I don't really know, why. Because the image is at the "right position" when scrolling up.